# How to find variance of a CIR process

Tags: statistics, ordinary-differential-equations

CIR process is defined as follows:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIR_process

I get an SDE form for d_Vt/dt, but can't proceed further.

Comment: The article lists the variance; do you need to show how to derive it?

Comment: Yes, I came up with a SDE, but not sure if it's the right one or how to solve it.